# Unwanted option of scrolling horizontally on webpage

Tags: html, css

My webpage was initially only vertically scrollable. When I added a relative-positioned div (containing text), suddenly the webpage was both vertically and (slightly) horizontally scrollable - despite the div being contained well within the webpage's original dimensions. Why is this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<link href="jerrell.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="jerrell.js"></script>  
</head>

<body style="background-color: #b2b2b2;">

<div class="top-bar">

<div id="strip">
<span style="color: #808080">_</span>
</div>
 <h1 id="name">
<span id="jerrel">Jerrell</span> 
<span id="michael">Cockerham</span>
</h1>

<h4 id="options">
<span id="splits">|</span> 
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><span id="go">About</span></a> 
 <span id="splits">|</span> 
 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><span id="go-two">Search</span></a> 
 <span id="splits">|</span>
 </h4>

 </div>

 <div class="welcome">
 <p id="welcome">Click to Begin</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mncourse">
  <table id="tissue">
  <tr id="posdep">
  <td id="posdepdat">
  <p id="high1">Positively Dependent</p>
  <p id="low1">Here is where I attempt to poetically express my woes.</p>
  </td>
  <td id="tramxdat">
  <p id="high2">Trail Mix</p>
  <p id="low2">Everything I find interesting in mathematics.</p>
   </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="cred">Tree photo taken with iPhone</div>
 </body>
</html>

 /* #66ffff (blu), white (wht), #535353 (gry) */



body {
 background: url(intric.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 height: 1200px;
}

#name {

 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 position: fixed;
 top: -20px;
 z-index: 1;
}



#jerrel {

 color: #66ffff;
}

#michael {

 color: white;
}



#strip {

 position: fixed;
 left: -50px;
 top: -10px;
 background-color: #535353;
 width: 2000px;
 height: 50px;
 opacity: .9;
}

#options {

 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 position: fixed;
 right: 5px;
 top: -11px;
 z-index: 1;
}



#splits {

 color: white;
}



#go {

 color: #66ffff;

}



#go-two {

 color: #66ffff;

}



#go:hover {

 color: white;
}



#go-two:hover {

 color: white;
}

#welcome {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 width: 400px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 top: 42%;
 color: white;
 font-size: 50px;
 z-index: 4;
}

.mncourse {
 position: fixed;
 text-align: center;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 42%;
}

#tissue {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#high1 {
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 font-size: 32px;
 color: #66ffff;
}

#low1 {
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#high2 {
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 font-size: 32px;
 color: #66ffff;
}

#low2 {
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 color: white;
font-size: 20px;
}

td {
padding: 40px;
}

#posdepdat {

}

#tramxdat {

}

.cred {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 left: 30px;
 top: 1180px;
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: Seeing an example would help.  The div may look contained, but there might be something like a margin causing the overflow.

Comment: obviously it became wider than the window, but without code (HTML and CSS) nobody can tell you why

Comment: @Jack sorry, just posted all my code.

Comment: @Johannes Sorry, just posted all my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.cred {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 left: 30px;
 top: 1180px;
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 color: red;
}
```

I think the `left: 30px`; is the problem here: It moves `.cred` to the right by 30 px without expanding its parent element. And since its (default) width is 100%, that's 100% plus 30px overall...

Comment: Deleting 'left: 30px' did fix the problem. But if I still wanted to move the element 30 pixels without warping the width of the webpage, how would I go about it?

Comment: add `padding-left: 30px;`

Comment: I see. I'll try that next time I need it.

Comment: Unrelated: my question was downvoted twice. Is it too simple for the site, or something?

Comment: @user5684138 I don't know - I didn't do it. But I think that was before you added all the code. So it works for you now?

Comment: @user5684138 Glad to help. Please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Says I need at least fifteen reputation.

Comment: Wait the checkmark. Done.

Comment: @user5684138 ah, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The box model extends passed it's parent container. You can get around this using `box-sizing: border-box` in the css or `overflow-x: hidden` on the container

Comment: Changing the box-sizing may resolve the issue (or maybe it's margin or a positioned child element).  Hiding the overflow would work, but try to find the real issue before resorting to that.

Comment: Just need more info. Some off the cusp resolutions for this issue that are common.

Comment: Sorry, just posted all my code.